# .net core 3.1 How to add HttpContext.Current and HttpContext.Current.Application[""]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I read a few posts here and seems like System.Web and HttpContext.Current are removed from .net core. I add the following in my startup.cs

services.addSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccesor>();

that did not work in adding HttpContext.Current to my class

In my class library, I install Microsoft.AspNetCore.http into my dependency. I added as DI to

```
public MyClass(IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor) {
  httpContextAccessor = _httpContextAccessor;
}
```

in my cs code the old code starts with

```
if(HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Application["Test"] != null])
```

What is the replacement, so far this does not work

```
httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session != null 

Not sure what is the equivalent to HttpContext.Current.Application["Test"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, register the service in Startup.cs,

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then you can call below code in any class, it replaces HttpContext.Current

```
private HttpContext _httpContext => new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
```

You can use `_httpContext.Items[]` instead of Application. (Test this before production)

Comment: I found a few complex ones but this one is short and sweet. Thanks mate.

Comment: HttpContext.Items[] holds the data only for the duration of the request, while HttpContext.Application is a global variable that holds the data at application level.
Maybe HttpContext.Application should be replaced with caching, there is a memory cache in .NET, or using other caching methods.